# Mongo random sampling on huge data very slow

Tags: mongodb, random, sampling

We have a collection with more than 20 million documents.
These documents store all the user activity related data for over a year and are around 2 - 3kb on average.
When we count based on a specific field the results are returned in 1.5 mins but the same query with 5% sample size I.e 1 million record takes more than 2.5 mins.
When should we use random sampling feature mongo?
Is there any optimization that we can do while using this feature.
Also the allowdiskuse has to set to true due to sort memory restrictions.

MongoDB version 3.6.2
Hardware spec - 3 Shards with 24 core, 128GB RAM, SSD Hard drive

```
Mongo sample doc :
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("579728dfc6df0a06af162df3"),
    "userid" : 3708399,
    "ts" : 160726143951,
    "lists" : [
        {
            "listid" : 119,
            "modified" : 160726143951,
            "entered" : 160726143951
        },
        {
            "listid" : 1220,
            "modified" : NumberLong("170405120718"),
            "entered" : NumberLong("170405120718")
        },
    ],
    "attributes" : {
        "email" : "example@example.com",
        "unique" : "sampleFk",
        "mobile" : "9********9",
        "d" : 0,
        "bl" : 0,
        "state" : "Statename",
        "name" : "firstname",
        "code" : "01000000184D38B12D6E18E382B7AFB441B0499EFBC2D275B7BEC1F574A19E0D4E385D09",
        "city" : "CityName",
        "age" : 26,
        "gender" : "Male",
        "country" : "CountryName",
    },
    "sms_sent" : [
        {
            "message_id" : 975,
            "sentdate" : 170405,
            "senttime" : 170235
        },
        {
            "message_id" : 1039,
            "sentdate" : 170418,
            "senttime" : 163251
        },
        {
            "message_id" : 1054,
            "sentdate" : 170421,
            "senttime" : 163223
        },
    ],
    "sms_delivered" : [
        {
            "message_id" : 975,
            "sentdate" : 170405,
            "senttime" : 170235
        },
        {
            "message_id" : 1039,
            "sentdate" : 170418,
            "senttime" : 163251
        }
    ],
    "email_sent" : [
        {
            "message_id" : 464,
            "sentdate" : 170411,
            "senttime" : 121215
        },
        {
            "message_id" : 478,
            "sentdate" : 170425,
            "senttime" : 104551
        }
    ],
    "sms_clicked" : [
        {
            "message_id" : 975,
            "clickdate" : 170405,
            "clicktime" : 171035,
            "linkid":15
        }
    ],
    "email_clicked" : [
        {
            "message_id" : 464,
            "sentdate" : 170411,
            "senttime" : 131215
            "linkid":56
        }
    ]
}
```

Average doc size : 2KB

```
Query : 
db.collection.aggregate(
        [
            {$sample:{size:1339576}},
            {$match:{"attributes.city":"Kolkata"}},{$count:"count"}
        ],{allowDiskUse:true})
```

Thanks

Comment: If you're always running the random sample on specific fields can you index those fields?

Comment: Actually there are multiple such fields: age of user, gender, location and other attributes which are dynamically created by our clients. These documents also store transactional data like email received by the user and the activities performed on them. So indexing all these info is not feasible.

Comment: What method do you use to do the random sampling, and how big is each document? Could you post an example document, your MongoDB version, and the hardware spec you're using?

Comment: I have added the required details

Comment: I am also facing a similar issue with $sample aggregation. Where normal query on entire collection takes less time than $sample aggregation with 5% sample size.